# Sharepoint 2013 authentication node js

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, windows-authentication, nodejs

is there any way authenticate by node js ? i want to use node web api using sharepoint 2013 auth by username and password.after user login i will reach sharepoint lists for crud operations. i used node-sp-auth but these codes doesnt work for me. still i am getting 401 error code.

`spauth
.getAuth('http://domain', {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'pass1',
    host: 'domain'
})
.then(data => {
    let headers = data.headers;
    headers['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
    let requestOpts = data.options;
    requestOpts.json = true;
    requestOpts.headers = headers;
    requestOpts.url = "http://domain/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('cari')/Items?";
    request.get(requestOpts).then(response => {
        console.log(response.d.Title);
    })
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [sp-request](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request) module. It does all authentication for you. You can use REST API without thinking about the auth:

```
import * as sprequest from 'sp-request';
let spr = sprequest.create(credentialOptions);
spr.get('http://sp2013dev/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'TestList\')')
  .then(response => {
    console.log('List Id: ' + response.body.d.Id);
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log('Ohhh, something went wrong...');
  });
```